# How can i Filter an exists in a range like query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have an index with workingHour as an nested object that contains day, stat and end.

    `class WorkingHourIndex(InnerDoc):
        day = Keyword()
        start = Date()
        end = Date()`

Everything is indexed properly now when i search for documents i want to perform a query with day and a time and i want elasticsearch to check if the day exists of not and if it does , does the time exists between start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
day_query = Q('term', working_hours__day='DAY_I_NEED')
time_query = Q('range', working_hours__start={'lt': TS}) & Q('range', working_hours__end={'gt': TS})
Search().query('nested', path='working_hours', query=day_query & time_query)
```